# Composer checkout out instead of downloading

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have created my own base project which I install in my projects using Composer. It is a gitrepository, stored on Github. Then I create releases and push them to Packagist. I can install the base project, but instead of downloading the package like other packages, it always does a checkout.

Is there another way to use composer to download your packages instead of downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of downloading a package: source and dist.

`--prefer-dist` is what you are looking for. It will fetch the zip archives from Github, instead of checking the git repository out, which is `--prefer-source`.

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your reply, but it didn't solve the issue. The package is still loaded as a git-repository

Comment: Please attach the output of a verbose mode run: `composer install --prefer-dist -vvv`. (During the run you should see Github URLs containing `zipball`.)